# How to copy existing column data and edit it in another column using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to copy one column in my excel file, and then before pasting it into another column in the same excel file, I would like to edit it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
XSSFCell oldCell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
XSSFCell newCell =  worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(2);

if(styleMap != null) {   
        if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){   
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
        } else{   
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();   
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);   
            if(newCellStyle == null){   
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);   
            }   
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
        }   

    }
```

Now the column I want to copy contains country code like this:

```
Country Code
US
PK
DE
JP
```

I would like to copy this data, but before posting it in a different column I would like to change them to this:

```
Revised Country Code
US
IN
DE
JP
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Why not you just copy the column to desired column and edit that... it will be easy...

Comment: I can easily do copy and edit the column in Excel, but I want to do that using Java instead.